# Google colab, run python script (.py) from jupyter Notebook (.ipynb)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to run a .py script for trainning a Neural Network from a jupyter notebook in Colab. I'm doing that because the python script needs some input arguments. Both, python script and jupyter notebook are Colab files and they are in synchronized Google Drive.
I attach an example:
(execution file in jupyter notebook)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGK2W.png)

I execute the python script as follows from the jupyter notebook:
!python3 /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/Tesis/prueba1.py --lr-find 1

Where --lr-find 1 is the input argument that my Neural Network needs.

Anyway, this doesn't work for me. The neural network don't show sign of starting training.

Have you tried something similar?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Share the python code also.

Comment: Please provide an example of whatever error you are getting

Comment: When I execute the jupyter Notebook, there's no error shown.
Only this code:

`Mounted at /content/gdrive/
att_unet_rate_finder.py  losses.py     prueba1.py     Set_completo
Dataset_completo_CZ  modelo.ipynb  __pycache__
ejecutar.ipynb   output        pyimagesearch`

Comment: Sorry, but python code is too large, it has got over 700 lines. It's a CNN, I used to execute it in Spyder (anaconda) and what I expect is to see the epochs evolution of the training.